# Mysql-Python Connector issues on different approaches

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-error-1064

In the process of downloading mysql connector, I've taken 3 approaches:-

1. The commonly advised pip approach where I think the PATH (Python on system; which I don't think I understand) fails me since it doesn't seem to install mysql.connector. It gives a deprecation, collects mysql.connector and launches an error.
2. Direct download through this site: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/ whereby I've changed security preferences(since it was an unidentified by apple developer) and tried downloading but the application doesn't appear anywhere on my desktop and I can't seem to find it anywhere else.
3. I followed this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ji8lqiBJe0 and everything went fine till 1:34. I don't use pycharm so I decided to directly write import mysql.connector on idle. 
   At first, it would give me this error:-

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql

Now it presents this error:-

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import mysql.connector
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/**init**.py", line 41, in 
    import dns.resolver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dns'

I can't seem to understand where 'dns module' comes from. Could anybody help me on how to proceed? I think I've exhausted every method at this point but can't find an error.

Answer (score 2):

Have you correctly install dnspython ?

```
pip install dnspython
```

https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython

and the connector for your OS
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/